# Liferay 7 GA3 wizard

Tags: database, liferay, wizard

When i started liferay 7 GA3 for the first time, the browser on my laptop automatically opened the wizard with user and database configuration. I left the default values (which is hypersoning database) and moved forward to the portal.
I now want to connect my liferay istance to a mysql database. I have changed this line in the portal-setup-wizard.properties:

setup.wizard.enabled from "no" to "yes"

But when i restart liferay the wizard do not show anymore.

Is there any other configuration i have to write in liferay files to make the wizard to show again? Or maybe i have to configure the database manually?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823

Answer (score 0):

In `portal-setup-wizard.properties` remove the line `setup.wizard.enabled=false`. The property takes only one value i.e false to tell the setup not to start the basic configuration wizard. The absence of `setup.wizard.enabled` in  `portal-setup-wizard.properties` will again trigger the basic configuration wizard.